# A group normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I'm doing b) and c).

If I assume $H$ is normal then $aH = Ha$ for all $a \in G \text{ and } N(H)$.

If $N(H) = G$ then $G$ is somehow normal to itself...? Hints appreciated on both of these.

Comment: Both (b) and (c) follow by simply applying the definitions.

Comment: Definitions of normality?

Comment: Of course, and the defintiions of all other terms involved. (Anything involving normality **has** to involve the definition of normality!)

Answer (score 1):

c) Since $aH=Ha$ for each $a\in N(H)$ it follows that $H$ is normal il $N(H)$.
b) If $N(H)=G$ then, by c), it follows that $H$ is normal in $G$. If $H$ is normal in $G$ and $a\in G$ then $aHa^{-1}=H$ hence $a\in N(H)$.This proves $G\subseteq N(H)$, hence $G=N(H)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the condition $a\in N(H)$, namely $aHa^{-1}=H$ is equivalent to $aH=Ha$. So, we get that *within* $N(H)$, $\ H$ is a normal subgroup.

In fact, $N(H)$ is the biggest subgroup of $G$ such that $H$ is normal in it.

In view of this, it is clear that $H$ is normal in $G$ iff $N(H)=G\ $ (i.e., $aH=Ha$ holds for *all* $a\in G$).

Comment: Thank you but why is the **iff** statement clear? To me it only seems that you derived from c) that it is true, bot not both ways.

Comment: $H$ is normal iff $\forall a\in G:\ aH=Ha$ i.e. iff $N(H)=G$.